# Why does "piping" a CharBuffer hang?

Tags: java, io, pipe

Why does the following method hang?

```
public void pipe(Reader in, Writer out) {
    CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.allocate(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    while( in.read(buf) >= 0 ) {
      out.append(buf.flip());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: you have to call `buf.clear()` between `read`s. Presumably, `read` is hanging because the buffer is full. The correct code is

```
public void pipe(Reader in, Writer out) {
    CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.allocate(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    while( in.read(buf) >= 0 ) {
      out.append(buf.flip());
      buf.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hanging? Looking at the Readable API, I'd expect it to busy loop returning 0 on each read if the buffer is full, but that's a guess since it doesn't explicitly say what 'attempts to read' means. Hanging might mean that because you're multiply-writing the output, you've blocked the output.

Comment: I didn't check the detailed behavior of the loop. Either read blocks or repeatedly returns 0. The net effect: the loop never terminates.

Comment: I guess for blocking to happen the output stream must be something with a finite capacity that isn't being drained, like a circular buffer - pretty rare case. Maybe I'm idiosyncratic in that I generally use "hang" to mean a deadlock rather than a livelock.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that it is a deadlock. The in.read(buf) locks the CharBuffer and prevents the out.append(buf) call.

That is assuming that CharBuffer uses locks (of some kind)in the implementation. What does the API say about the class CharBuffer?

Edit: Sorry, some kind of short circuit in my brain... I confused it with something else.

Answer (score 0):

CharBuffers don't work with Readers and Writers as cleanly as you might expect. In particular, there is no `Writer.append(CharBuffer buf)` method. The method called by the question snippet is `Writer.append(CharSequence seq)`, which just calls `seq.toString()`. The `CharBuffer.toString()` method does return the string value of the buffer, but it doesn't drain the buffer. The subsequent call to `Reader.read(CharBuffer buf)` gets an already full buffer and therefore returns 0, forcing the loop to continue indefinitely.

Though this feels like a hang, it is in fact appending the first read's buffer contents to the writer every pass through the loop. So you'll either start to see a lot of output in your destination or the writer's internal buffer will grow, depending on how the writer is implemented.

As annoying as it is, I'd recommend a char[] implementation if only because the CharBuffer solution winds up building at least two new char[] every pass through the loop.

```
public void pipe(Reader in, Writer out) throws IOException {
    char[] buf = new char[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int count = in.read(buf);
    while( count >= 0 ) {
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
        count = in.read(buf);
    }
}
```

I'd recommend only using this if you need to support converting between two character encodings, otherwise a ByteBuffer/Channel or byte[]/IOStream implementation would be preferable even if you're piping characters.